403 Forbidden error in normal HTTP-POST
Why I get that 403-error after 60 succecsfull HTTP-POST request ? If I wait 10 seconds and continue, no that kind of error orrurs in last 5 HTTP-POST request. But if I repeat my test, it happens again.
The time between HTTP-POST was just below 1 sec, about 0.9 secs.
The first was 22:10:15,955 and the last succesful was 22:11:12,973.

More detail is required.

Probably you have a rate-limiting configuration, WAF, Firewall or daemon somewhere that is trying to prevent abuse.
